# Can someone prove that the sequence $1,\tan(1),\tan(\tan(1)),\ldots$ is infinite? If so, can someone prove if it diverges or converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

> Can someone prove that the sequence $1, \tan(1),\tan(\tan(1)),\ldots$ is infinite? If so, can someone prove if it diverges or converges?

Intuitively, this sequence is infinite as it's hard to hit exactly at $n\pi+\frac{1}{2}\pi$, but how can someone prove that?

Also, is there a solution of the sequence $A, \tan(A), \tan(\tan(A)),\ldots$ for any given value $A$?

The context of this question is on a [Zhihu question](https://www.zhihu.com/question/582129095/answer/2903965823) where someone asked if there is any sequence that one do not know if it converges or diverges and someone answers with this sequence.

I believe that this sequence might finally converge to one of the stationary points where $\tan(x)=x$, but I have no idea  which one it will end up for any given value $A$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Qian, what do you mean when you say “solution of the sequence” ? Do you mean to ask if there exists the limit of the sequence ?

Comment: @Angelo Just the same problem applied to any given value A, instead of 1. For some value like $A=\tan^{-1}(\frac{\pi}{2})$, the sequence ends up at the second item, and for other value, the sequence might be infinite.

Comment: Looking at the first few iterates, it seems that the sequence $a_{n+1} = \tan(a_n), a_1=1$ has infinitely many positive and negative terms. But then near $0$, we have $x< \tan(x)$ so $0$ isn't an "attractive" fixed point. Using this argument, it should be possible to prove that the sequence doesn't converge.

Answer (score 1):

It converges near a solution of $\tan( x )=x$ if the derivative is between $1$ and $-1$ there.  But its derivative is $\sec^2(x)\ge1$ so it doesn't converge.

The derivative of, for example $\tan(\tan(\tan(x))))$ is a product of squared secants, so that doesn't converge either.

Comment: I guess if it ever hits one of the solutions to $\tan(x)=x$ precisely, it will stay there, and therefore converge

Comment: Only a countable number of initial values will ever hit any of the solutions, so almost all starting points never do